# Where can I convert x to float in this Python function?

Tags: python, function

How can I make this function return and print a float:

```
x = input ("Enter 5 numbers:")

def average(x):
       return sum(x) / len(x)

print average(x)
```

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+division+float

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Right, but he's on Python 2 apparently and should be using `raw_input()`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: That "duplicate" is a long way away from helping him in this situation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I don't see your point. Note that using `input` the `x` in his code is a list/tuple of numbers so the **only** problem he has (and that ha also has asked explicitly) is how to do floating point arithmetic when the input are integers. And that's *exactly* what the duplicate question is about.

Comment: So since he's on Python 2, then I was wrong above about what he asked about. The only thing left then is the float conversion, so the duplicate should be fine then.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks, the duplicate question solves my problem perfectly! I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.x, `int` object divided by `int` yields `int`.

You should convert one (or both) of the operand to `float` to get `float` result:

```
>>> 10 / 2
5
>>> float(10) / 2
5.0
```

Or turn on true division using [`__future__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 10 / 2
5.0
```